# ROS - out of control turtle

Tags: python, python-2.7, ros

I have a leader turtle and three follower turtles. The followers are following using the tf2 transform method.

Two turtles seem to follow fine, but one has been on the happy juice, and does its own thing. Is there any way to stop this? Some times it comes correct and will move to the right location, but this isn't the behaviour I am hoping for.

Screen shot below:

[image]

The main file is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import rospy

import math
import tf2_ros
import geometry_msgs.msg
import turtlesim.srv
from turtlesim.msg import Pose
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
import time
from random import randint
from com760_assign_summer_ws_pkg.msg import bxxxxxxxxLeaderMessage

# name = ""
instruction = ""
message = ""
f2x = None

global PI, x, y, x, yaw
PI = 3.1415926535897
x=0
y=0
z=0
yaw=0
tolerance = 0.1
condition = 0

def callback(data):
    global instruction, message
    instruction = data.instructionID
    message = data.message
    # print("Instruction is: ", data.instructionID)
    # return data

def msg_listener():
    # global data
    # print("In listener")
    # rospy.Subscriber('leader_chatter', bxxxxxxxxLeaderMessage, callback)
    # print(data)
    pass

def msg_talker():
    # print("In talker")
    # sg_pub = rospy.Publisher('leader_chatter', bxxxxxxxxLeaderMessage, queue_size=10)

    msg = b00830189LeaderMessage()
    msg.instructionID = 0
    msg.message = "Followers are to gather in formation"
    msg_pub.publish(msg) # The message is cintinuously published
    msg_listener()

def rotate():
    #Starts a new node
    # rospy.init_node('robot_cleaner', anonymous=True)
    # velocity_publisher = rospy.Publisher('/leader_turtle/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)
    # vel_msg = Twist()

    speed = 90.0
    angle = 90.0
    
    
    clockwise = randint(0,1) # 0 = False, so, antilockwise, 1 - True, so, clockwise
    # clockwise = False

    #Converting from angles to radians
    angular_speed = speed*2*PI/360
    relative_angle = angle*2*PI/360

    #We wont use linear components
    vel.linear.x=0
    vel.linear.y=0
    vel.linear.z=0
    vel.angular.x = 0
    vel.angular.y = 0


    # Checking if our movement is CW or CCW
    if clockwise:
        vel.angular.z = -abs(angular_speed)
    else:
        vel.angular.z = abs(angular_speed)
    # Setting the current time for distance calculus
    t0 = rospy.Time.now().to_sec()
    current_angle = 0


    while(current_angle < relative_angle):
        # rospy.loginfo("Rotating")
        pub.publish(vel)
        t1 = rospy.Time.now().to_sec()
        current_angle = angular_speed*(t1-t0)


    #Forcing stop
    vel.angular.z = 0
    pub.publish(vel)
    # rospy.spin()


def poseCallback(pose_message):
    global x
    global y, z, yaw
    x= pose_message.x
    y= pose_message.y
    yaw = pose_message.theta
    

def f1_poseCallback(f1_pose_message):
    # Function to get the polition of the follower 1 turtle
    global f1x, f1y, f1z, f1yaw
    f1x= f1_pose_message.x
    f1y= f1_pose_message.y
    f1yaw = f1_pose_message.theta
  
def f2_poseCallback(f2_pose_message):
    # Function to get the polition of the follower 2 turtle
    global f2x, f2y, f2z, f2yaw
    f2x= f2_pose_message.x
    f2y= f2_pose_message.y
    f2yaw = f2_pose_message.theta
  
def f3_poseCallback(f3_pose_message):
    # Function to get the polition of the follower 3 turtle
    global f3x, f3y, f3z, f3yaw
    f3x= f3_pose_message.x
    f3y= f3_pose_message.y
    f3yaw = f3_pose_message.theta

def pose_callback(pose):
    global robot_x
    rospy.loginfo("Robot X = %f : Y = %f : Z = %f \n", pose.x, pose.y, pose.theta)
    robot_x = pose.x

def straight_line_setup():
    # --- Moves the turtle in a straight line after it has rotated --- #
    vel.linear.x = 0.5 # Speed
    vel.linear.y = 0
    vel.linear.z = 0
    
    vel.angular.x = 0
    vel.angular.y = 0
    vel.angular.z = 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    global vel, pub
    rospy.init_node('tf2_turtle_listener')
    
    rospy.Subscriber('leader_chatter', b00830189LeaderMessage, callback)
    msg_pub = rospy.Publisher('leader_chatter', b00830189LeaderMessage, queue_size=10)
    
    loop_rate = rospy.Rate(10) # Publishing 10Hz
    
    turtlename = 'turtle1'
    position_topic = "/turtle1/pose"
    pose_subscriber = rospy.Subscriber(position_topic, Pose, poseCallback)
    
    follow1_topic = "/turtle2/pose"
    follower1_subscriber = rospy.Subscriber(follow1_topic, Pose, f1_poseCallback)
    follow2_topic = "/turtle3/pose"
    follower1_subscriber = rospy.Subscriber(follow2_topic, Pose, f3_poseCallback)
    follow3_topic = "/turtle4/pose"
    follower1_subscriber = rospy.Subscriber(follow3_topic, Pose, f3_poseCallback)
    
    
    x0=x #  x0 - starts point
    y0=y
    distance_moved = 0.0
    
    vel = Twist()

    pub = rospy.Publisher('/turtle1/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)
    # rospy.Subscriber('/turtle1/pose', Pose, pose_callback)
    
    time.sleep(5) # Allowing time for everything to get set up before next thing happens
    
    # ------- Rotating, hopefully ------ ~
    rotate() # This function will go off and rotate the turtle either closewise or anticlockwise.
    
    time.sleep(3)
    # --- Moves the turtle in a straight line after it has rotated --- #
    straight_line_setup() # call this instead of the commented code above

    tfBuffer = tf2_ros.Buffer()
    listener = tf2_ros.TransformListener(tfBuffer)
    
    
    # ----------------- Spawning turtles ------------------ #
    rospy.wait_for_service('spawn')
    spawner = rospy.ServiceProxy('spawn', turtlesim.srv.Spawn)
    turtle_name_2 = rospy.get_param('turtle', 'turtle2')
    # spawner(randint(2,7), randint(1,9), 0, turtle_name_2)
    spawner(1, 1, 0, turtle_name_2)

    rospy.wait_for_service('spawn')
    spawner = rospy.ServiceProxy('spawn', turtlesim.srv.Spawn)
    turtle_name_3 = rospy.get_param('turtle', 'turtle3')
    # spawner(randint(7,9), randint(1,9), 0, turtle_name_3)
    spawner(1, 4, 0, turtle_name_3)
    
    rospy.wait_for_service('spawn')
    spawner = rospy.ServiceProxy('spawn', turtlesim.srv.Spawn)
    turtle_name_4 = rospy.get_param('turtle', 'turtle4')
    spawner(1, 8, 0, turtle_name_4)

    turtle_vel_2 = rospy.Publisher('%s/cmd_vel' % turtle_name_2, geometry_msgs.msg.Twist, queue_size=1)
    turtle_vel_3 = rospy.Publisher('%s/cmd_vel' % turtle_name_3, geometry_msgs.msg.Twist, queue_size=1)
    turtle_vel_4 = rospy.Publisher('%s/cmd_vel' % turtle_name_4, geometry_msgs.msg.Twist, queue_size=1)

    rate = rospy.Rate(10.0)
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        
        msg_talker()
        
        # Now, I want an if-statement. If 0, for the followers, if 0, do the other thing
        if(instruction == 0):
        # pub.publish(vel) # publishing to leader turtle (i.e. main turtle)
            try:
                past = rospy.Time.now() - rospy.Duration(5.0)

                trans2 = tfBuffer.lookup_transform(turtle_name_2, 'carrot1', rospy.Time.now(), rospy.Duration(1.0))
                trans3 = tfBuffer.lookup_transform(turtle_name_3, 'carrot2', rospy.Time.now(), rospy.Duration(1.0))
                trans4 = tfBuffer.lookup_transform(turtle_name_4, 'carrot3', rospy.Time.now(), rospy.Duration(1.0))
                # trans3 = tfBuffer.lookup_transform('turtle3', 'carrot2', rospy.Time.now(), rospy.Duration(1.0))
            except (tf2_ros.LookupException, tf2_ros.ConnectivityException, tf2_ros.ExtrapolationException):
                # raise
                rate.sleep()
                continue

            msg2 = geometry_msgs.msg.Twist()
            msg2.angular.z = 4 * math.atan2(trans2.transform.translation.y, trans2.transform.translation.x)
            msg2.linear.x = 0.5 * math.sqrt(trans2.transform.translation.x ** 2 + trans2.transform.translation.y ** 2)
            
            msg3 = geometry_msgs.msg.Twist()
            msg3.angular.z = 4 * math.atan2(trans3.transform.translation.y, trans3.transform.translation.x)
            msg3.linear.x = 0.5 * math.sqrt(trans3.transform.translation.x ** 2 + trans3.transform.translation.y ** 2)
            
            msg4 = geometry_msgs.msg.Twist()
            msg4.angular.z = 4 * math.atan2(trans4.transform.translation.y, trans4.transform.translation.x)
            msg4.linear.x = 0.5 * math.sqrt(trans4.transform.translation.x ** 2 + trans4.transform.translation.y ** 2)
            
            turtle_vel_2.publish(msg2)
            turtle_vel_3.publish(msg3)
            turtle_vel_4.publish(msg4)

            pub.publish(vel) # Moves the leader turtle
            
            if(((x > 10.5) or (x < 0.5)) or ((y > 10.5) or (y < 0.5))):
                print("Ah!! A wall")
                vel.linear.x = 0
                vel.linear.y = 0
                pub.publish(vel)
        else:
            # print("It isn't 0, you crazy fool!")
            pass

        rate.sleep()
```

Then I also have the following, in separate files. The only difference is the `t.child_frame_id` is different in all three. The other two have `carrot2` and then `carrot3`, and the x- and y-locations:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import rospy
import tf2_ros
import tf2_msgs.msg
import geometry_msgs.msg


class FixedTFBroadcaster:

    def __init__(self):
        self.pub_tf = rospy.Publisher("/tf", tf2_msgs.msg.TFMessage, queue_size=1)

        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            # Run this loop at about 10Hz
            rospy.sleep(0.1)

            t = geometry_msgs.msg.TransformStamped()
            t.header.frame_id = "turtle1"
            t.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
            t.child_frame_id = "carrot1"
            t.transform.translation.x = -1.0
            t.transform.translation.y = -1.0
            t.transform.translation.z = 0.0

            t.transform.rotation.x = 0.0
            t.transform.rotation.y = 0.0
            t.transform.rotation.z = 0.0
            t.transform.rotation.w = 1.0

            tfm = tf2_msgs.msg.TFMessage([t])
            self.pub_tf.publish(tfm)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('fixed_tf2_broadcaster')
    tfb = FixedTFBroadcaster()

    rospy.spin()
```

Launch file:

```
  <launch>
      <node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtlesim_node" name="sim"/>
      <!-- <node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtle_teleop_key" name="teleop" output="screen"/> -->


    <node name="turtle1_tf2_broadcaster" pkg="com760_week5_ws_pkg" type="turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py" respawn="false" output="screen" >
      <param name="turtle" type="string" value="turtle1" />
    </node>
    <node name="turtle2_tf2_broadcaster" pkg="com760_week5_ws_pkg" type="turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py" respawn="false" output="screen" >
      <param name="turtle" type="string" value="turtle2" /> 
    </node>
    
    <node name="turtle3_tf2_broadcaster" pkg="com760_week5_ws_pkg" type="turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py" respawn="false" output="screen" >
      <param name="turtle" type="string" value="turtle3" /> 
    </node>
    
    <node name="turtle4_tf2_broadcaster" pkg="com760_week5_ws_pkg" type="turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py" respawn="false" output="screen" >
      <param name="turtle" type="string" value="turtle4" /> 
    </node>
    
    
    
    
    <node pkg="com760_week5_ws_pkg" type="turtle_tf2_listener.py" name="listener" output="screen"/>
    
    <node pkg="com760_week5_ws_pkg" type="fixed_tf2_broadcaster.py" name="broadcaster_fixed" output="screen"/>
    <node pkg="com760_week5_ws_pkg" type="fixed_tf2_broadcaster_1.py" name="broadcaster_fixed_1" output="screen"/>
    <node pkg="com760_week5_ws_pkg" type="fixed_tf2_broadcaster_2.py" name="broadcaster_fixed_2" output="screen"/>
    
    <!-- <node pkg="com760_week5_ws_pkg" type="dynamic_tf2_broadcaster.py" name="broadcaster_dynamic" output="screen"/> -->

  </launch>
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, there is absolutely nothing we can do.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code. Possible a namespace issue? Are these normal turtlebots or have you written any extra code for them? Launch files would be helpful too

Comment: @BTables I have added the code and launch files. The main section of code is in the file `turtle_tf2_listener.py`, then I have three broadcaster files. To be honest, the launch file does seem to work, but I could just be lucky in how it is put together, we never really covered them that much.

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts, I have added the code and the launch file code too. Cheers.

Comment: @ofithch79 are you sure those transforms are being retrieved correctly? Also the transform between turtle frames shouldn’t be fixed since turtles can(and do) move independently.

Comment: Seems to me like the first two shouldn’t really be tracking, but maybe that’s just lucky starting position. If you move turtle 4 to spawn closer to the other two does it work then?

Comment: @BTables I went with the fixed frames because the three followers follow the lead in a straight line. And I have all three with the turtle1 as the header frame. But I will look into the dynamic frame and see does that help. And I have has turtles starting really close to one another and one still seems to go off track. Can I ask, what makes you think the first two shouldn't be tracking?

Answer (score 1):

Your main file looks fine, so I would think it's due to a typo in one of your extra transform files. That being said there is one way to greatly simplify the problem. ROS is made to be module and as such duplicate nodes/code(in this case turtles) should be launched separately in the launch file.

For example, here there should only be one turtle spawned in each python file. First, you should have a single file that handles all of the lead turtle code. Then you should have another *single* file for one single follow turtle. Your launch file should use this file to create 3 nodes passing in appropriate turtle-number specific params. For example:

```
<node pkg="com760_week5_ws_pkg" type="turtle_tf2_listener.py" name="listener1" output="screen">
    <param name="turtle_number" value="turtle_1" />
    <param name="start_position" value=[0,1,8]>
</node>
<node pkg="com760_week5_ws_pkg" type="turtle_tf2_listener.py" name="listener2" output="screen">
    <param name="turtle_number" value="turtle_2" />
    <param name="start_position" value=[0,1,0]>
</node>
```

Not only does this fit the ROS paradigms it greatly reduces the chance of copy/paste errors and has a might tighter guarantee that nodes/turtles are running the same code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will see if there are typos and try to implement the launch file suggestions. Thanks again.